# Can we store App-scope-id in our database, when using FB js SDk + login API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

- We are using FB login to allow end users to login in to our
  application.
- We are not storing user name/email in our database.
- Just to uniquely identify the user when he/she logs in again we were
  storing "third_party_id".
- However, after 3.0 release this parameter
  is deprecated. so we are planning to store id in our application.

**So can we store App-scope-id in our database with out requiring for App review?** Since we are not storing any user info or we are not fetching such info from facebook.

Comment: that does not really qualify for an answer, and i only need more characters, but....yes

Comment: @lusch as per facebook [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/changelog) app-scope-id is not mentioned in App-Review. So, my question is that is it allowed/legal to store the App-scope-id in our own database.

Comment: no one can really use the app scoped id except your app...not sure why it should be a problem, how else would you identify returning users? if you are unsure, tell the user about it.